# How to Display Validation Errors Next to Each Related Input Field in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Default solution is trivial:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<ul id="login-validation-errors" class="validation-errors">
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <li class="validation-error-item">{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

and I can include `errors.blade.php` anywhere.

Is there any way to extract each element and display it next to input field that holds the value that failed?

I assume that would require me to define a lot of conditional `if` statements next to each input, right?

How to sort this problem? Could you give me any examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" required="required" name="name" type="text" id="name">
        {!! $errors->first('name', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Lets say the text input `name` has multiple errors like `'name'  => 'required|min:20'`, then how do we show multiple error lines here?

Comment: @mapmalith These two errors are not possible at the same time

Comment: it is possible. foreach ($errors->get('email') as $message) {
    //
}

Answer (score 5):

@Zorx has given a right solution. But what if there are multiple errors and you want to display all of them at once.

According to the documentation you could use:

**Retrieving All Error Messages For A Field**

```
foreach ($errors->get('email') as $message) {
//
}
```

If you are validating an array form field, you may retrieve all of the messages for each of the array elements using the * character:

```
foreach ($errors->get('attachments.*') as $message) {
//
}
```

**Retrieving All Error Messages For All Fields**

```
foreach ($errors->all() as $message) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Laravel Introduced The @error Directive in version 6 and 7

```
<input id="title" type="text" name="title" class="@error('title') is-invalid @enderror">

@error('title')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

[documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Validation individual error message and input border with red color using bootstrap classes and Laravel's `$errors` directive

**Input field with red border color**

```
<input type="text" name="fullName" class="form-control {{($errors->first('fullName') ? 'is-invalid' : '')}}" value="{{old('fullName');}}">
//Or
<input type="text" name="fullName" class="form-control @error('fullName') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{old('fullName');}}">
```

**Individual validation error message**

```
@error('fullName') <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div> @enderror
```