# Why Laravel blade @error doesnt show the error?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade, fortify

I was testing this new Laravel fortify with Laravel 8 and got into an odd issue that I've never seen before.
for the input field validation of the registration form and login form, the blade error message that I made doesn't show if I don't use `@error('[field name]') is-invalid @enderror` to add the `is-invalid` class to the input field.

any idea why is that?

this is how I'm showing the error:

```
@error('[field name]')
   <span class="invalid-feedback is-invalid" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
   </span>
@enderror
```

Here id the demo code I made:
https://gitlab.com/sxshateri/laravel-fortify

Comment: Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: im using laravel 8 and fortify.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885413/how-to-display-validation-errors-next-to-each-related-input-field-in-laravel-5/55030568#55030568